# Find and replace string with sed

Tags: sed, replace

I need to do a multi-file find and replace with nothing (delete) using sed. I have the line:

So replace the line:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="there could be anything here">
```

With '' (nothing) in all files in and under the current dir.

I have got this so far:

```
sed -e 's/<meta name="keywords" content=".*>//g' myfile.html'
```

But I know this is only going to remove the < or > tags. How can I match against

```
<meta name="keywords" content="
```

and delete everything from that to the next

```
>
```

I also need to do it for all files in and under (recursively) the current directory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: HTML and regex don't go together.

Comment: Please stop answering this anywhere, you're not making any point nor sense. @Barney, what do you really want to do? (btw your first regex should work, that is, depending on what you really want to do)

Comment: Edited, hopefully it's a little clearer? Sorry about that

Comment: Are you sure this is always going to be a single line? You won't have a case where the closing '>' is on another line? And will this be the _only_ thing on the line(s) (you talk about deleting the line, but your code is deleting within a line).

Comment: Your posted script WILL do what you say you want, i.e. `match against <meta name="keywords" content=" and delete everything from that to the next >` so it's impossible so far to figure out what you want. Posting a **few** lines of truly representative sample input and expected output would help.

Answer (score 1):

sed has the delete directive try using

```
sed -e '/<meta name="keywords"/d' myfile.html
```